# Gsuite share with anyone with the link from mobile

Tags: google-drive, google-workspace

I have Gsuite for education and I am using the Drive space.
From my PC I can share a file, get link and select to make it visible to **anyone with the link (public)**. However, when I share a link from the Drive app on Android, the max share level I can get to is **anyone with the link *within the domain***

I have another Gsuite account that also seems to have this limitation.
I have contacted my Uni and they claim to have it to the most relaxed level and that it cannot be changed. Is this the case? Can you really not get a fully public link to a file in a Gsuite account Drive space?

Thanks!